# onClick remove class from div

Tags: jquery, html, css

html

```
    <div class="perWatchVideo" id="remove">
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="link" id="link" name="link" placeholder="Place Link here" class="linkInput">
            <button class="btn btn-primary loadVideo">Load Video!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
jquery
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("loadVideo").click(function(){
            $("#remove").removeClass("preWachVideo");
        });
     });
```

Inside the div tags, I have created a class called perWatchVideo. When I click the button, I want to get rid of this class and replace it with the class postWatchVideo, a different class. How can I do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you forgot `.` before `loadVideo` to be `$(".loadVideo")` instead of `$("loadVideo")`

You need to use `.addClass()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".loadVideo").click(function(){
      $("#remove").removeClass("preWachVideo").addClass('postWatchVideo');
    });
 });
```

or if you need to toggle classes on each click you can use `toggleClass();`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".loadVideo").click(function(){
       $("#remove").toggleClass("preWachVideo postWatchVideo");
     });
});
```

> Note: *ID suppose to be unique* If you have more than one element with `id="remove"` your code will work just with the first `#remove element`

so you will need to change it from

```
<div class="perWatchVideo" id="remove">
```

to

```
<div class="perWatchVideo remove">
```

then your code should looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".loadVideo").click(function(){
      $(this).closest(".remove").removeClass("preWachVideo").addClass('postWatchVideo');
   });
});
```